# Kustomize doesn't adapt workloadSelector label of sidecar when using nameSuffix?

Tags: istio, kustomize

I have a sidecar like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: testns
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: test
...
```

and a kustomization like:

```
resources:
  - ../../base

nameSuffix: -dev
```

But kustomize doesn't adapt the workloadSelector label app to `test-dev` as I would expect it to do. The name suffix is only appended to the name of the sidecar. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default kustomize `namePrefix` and `nameSuffix` only apply to `metadata/name` for all resources.

There are a set of configured [nameReferences](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md#builtin-namereference) that will also be transformed with the appropriate name, but they are limited to resource names.

See here for more info: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md#prefixsuffix-transformer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How would you overcome this issue? Using a patch?

Comment: Yes, based on your example I'm assuming you were hoping to target specific workloads, in which case you could write patches to set the appropriate label in the pod spec, and an additional corresponding patch to update the `workloadSelector`.  

It is hard to know without more information but it seems like it would be easier to reason about with a more specific `workloadSelector` so you could write a single patch that added a label like `sidecar: enabled` to your pods/workloads.